# How to check current set local notification?

Tags: react-native, notifications

Our app allows a user to set a daily notification reminding them to use our app. We have a bug currently, so I'm wanting to see what current notifications are set.

I've read the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) and found `PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications(callback);` but I'm struggling on how to implement it. Really, I just want to console log scheduled notifications.

Any help would be great!

For reference, this is how we are currently setting the notification

```
if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      // iOS
      PushNotificationIOS.scheduleLocalNotification({
        alertTitle: config.reminder.title,
        alertBody:  config.reminder.text,
        fireDate: tomorrow,
        repeatInterval: "day",
      });
    } else if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      PushNotification.scheduleLocalNotification({
        title: config.reminder.title,
        body: config.reminder.text,
        date: tomorrow,
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a callback return so try it like this and you should get your array of Scheduled Local Notifications

```js
PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications((data) => {
  console.log('ScheduledLocalNotifications: ', data);
});
```